# Trying to replace value of an dynamic element

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

i am trying to set value of an dynamic html element with value retrieve from database which i have stored in a variable.
Aspx side

```
<tr id="parTr1" runat="server">
                    <td id="parTd1" style="font-size: 10pt;" class="widthtbl">
                        <div><b>Parameter</b></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPar_Tr" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Aspx.cs
on page load i am calling StdSize_Toler() function in that i am storing value in variable string STd1Val and also generating dynamic table 
Now 
in dynamic table

```
 var lblPar_Trm = "<table><tr><th>UoM</th></tr><tr><td id='STd1'>ABC</td></tr>
lblPar_Tr.Text = lblPar_Trm + "</table>";
```

i am trying to change the hardcode value 'ABC' with value obtained in variable 'STd1Val'
Not getting any idea how to do .Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using hardcoded value  storing variable value in concatenated form

```
var lblPar_Trm = "<table><tr><th>UoM</th></tr><tr><td id='STd1'>"+STd1Val+"</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you have to use :

```
element.replace("actual value", "new value");
```

Be sure the element you trying to apply a replace on is a str.

Need more informations about "replace()" ? Source of my answer :
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp